# useEffect only running when value is added to array but no when value is removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm new to React and am trying to create a basic schedule app. I have four files: "App.js", "AllEvents.js", "Event.js", and "NavBar.js"

My App.js is pretty basic and I've only included relevant parts

```
const App = () => {
  const [eventFilters, setEventFilters] = useState([]);
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllEvents();
  }, []);

  const getAllEvents = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const data = await response.json();

    setAllEvents(data.events);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar eventFilters={eventFilters} setEventFilters={setEventFilters}/>
      <AllEvents allEvents={allEvents} eventFilters={eventFilters}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In AllEvents.js I actually render out the events I get from getAllEvents() in App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Event from './Event';

const AllEvents = ({allEvents, eventFilters}) => {
  const [filteredEvents, setFilteredEvents] = useState([]);

  const getFilteredEvents = () => {
    setFilteredEvents(allEvents.filter(event => eventFilters.includes(event.eventType)));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      getFilteredEvents();
  }, [eventFilters.length]);

  return(
    <div>
        {filteredEvents.map((event) => (
            <Event 
              key={event.id}
              title={event.name}
              description={event.description}
              type={event.eventType}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In NavBar.js I set eventFilters based on which buttons are pressed

```
const navBar = ( {eventFilters, setEventFilters} ) => {
  const eventFilterHandler = (e) => {
    var passedFilter = e.target.value;
    var arrayContainsFilter = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < eventFilters.length; i++){
      if(eventFilters[i] == passedFilter){
        eventFilters.splice(i, 1);
        setEventFilters(eventFilters);
        arrayContainsFilter = true;
      }
    }

    if(!arrayContainsFilter){
      setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat(passedFilter));
    }
    console.log(eventFilters);
  };

  return(
    <div>
      
      <div onClick={eventFilterHandler}>
        <button value="ALL"> All </button>
        <button value="WORKSHOP"> Workshop </button>
        <button value="MINIEVENT"> Minievent </button>
        <button value="SPEAKER"> Speaker </button>
        <button value="MEAL"> Meal </button>
        <button value="OTHER"> Other </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

When I add values to eventFilters by clicking on the buttons, UseEffect in AllEvents.js runs and re-renders the page. However, when I remove values, the useEffect doesn't run and the page doesn't re-render. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < eventFilters.length; i++){
  if(eventFilters[i] == passedFilter){
    eventFilters.splice(i, 1);
    setEventFilters(eventFilters);
    arrayContainsFilter = true;
  }
}

if(!arrayContainsFilter){
  setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat(passedFilter));
}
```

In the loop, you're *mutating* the existing state (never do that in React!) and passing the mutated state to the set state function. Since the old state is `===` to the new state, there is no re-rendering.

Never mutate state in React. Instead, create a *copy*. Here, you can use `filter`:

```
if (eventFilters.includes(passedFilter)) {
  setEventFilters(
    eventFilters.filter(item => item !== passedFilter)
  );
} else {
  setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat(passedFilter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i get it you want to re-render the component after the data is changed.But it only changes when data is added not hen it is removed.This might be because of useEffect you only run it when you are getting the data.Previously

```
useEffect(() => {
    getAllEvents();
  }, []);
```

Now

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getAllEvents();
  }, [allEvents]);
```

Run the useEffect when data is changed.If it is removed or added